# Spring Boot module not found error

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-9

I am creating a Spring Boot application on Java 9. If I keep parent as below in pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and `module-info.java` as:

```
module com.journaldev.spring.SpringWebflux {
    requires reactor.core;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.webflux;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
}
```

Then I get errors as module not found.

```
module-info.java:[2,21] module not found: reactor.core
module-info.java:[3,20] module not found: spring.web
module-info.java:[4,20] module not found: spring.context
module-info.java:[5,20] module not found: spring.webflux
module-info.java:[6,20] module not found: spring.boot
module-info.java:[7,25] module not found: spring.boot.autoconfigure
```

If I lower the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to `2.0.0.RELEASE` then this error is gone. I am trying to understand why?

Comment: If a version fallback works could probably be a change mentioned in their release notes or a bug with the release. Did you look out what changed with the release?

Comment: No I couldn't find anything specific that could tell me about this issue.

Comment: Please post your entire POM.

Comment: There is nothing that has changed in that area and the 2.0.1.RELEASE jar does contain the automatic-module-name entry. Perhaps the jar is corrupted on your machine or something? Can you open it in your local repo and check the entry is there in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: That jar is not present, noticed some warning as: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ SpringWebflux ---
[WARNING] ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature). Removed repository and doing a fresh build, let's see if that works.

Comment: clearing the repository fixed the issue, may be some jar got corrupted. Thanks for the suggestion to look for jar.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll why module-info.java is not present? why taken automatic module approach ?

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments, the jar was corrupted (which can happen when you upgrade to a newer version and something wrong happened at network level). Clearing that from the maven or gradle cache is usually enough to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, ran a gradle clean then gradle build and it resolved.